# how to compile .SCSS to .CSS project files in template

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm a beginner developer and am only familiar with HTML/CSS/JS and some basics of their frameworks.

I've recently purchased this Template from template monster for a project (https://www.templatemonster.com/intense-multipurpose-html-template.html?aff=template-static)

WHAT I NEED - Want to change the primary theme color of the template.

WHAT ALL I DID -
According to the documentation, it said -

"To replace main colors of the template, you need to open the file _color-default.scss, and replace the values of $primary, $secondary, $gray-base...(depends on your template) variables with the necessary colors. **Afterward, compile SCSS into CSS.**"

[image]

THE PROBLEM I'M FACING - I'm completely new to the concept of SCSS, can somebody please help me on how to compile these SCSS files to CSS, as the document says.

THIS IS MY Project, if it helps -
[image]

Comment: you can install 'live sass compiler' extension in vscode. or you can use gulp.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a scss compiler like node-sass, live-sass or gulp. An easier option is to use online compilers like http://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php or the one in [CodePen](https://codepen.io)